# twilio leave localparticipant from room

Tags: javascript, twilio

on twilio video confreence, I am local participant and 4 remote participants. I want to leave the room. SO used the code as `room.disconnect();` . While using this I have triggered by `Participantdisconnected` event. But other participants are available in the room. It shows others leave the rooms.

How to handle the local participant's disconnected event.

I want to restrict the same user entered in to same room multiple times. I cal connect via web and phone. How to restrict this.

Comment: I'm a bit confused about the question--when `Participantdisconnected` is triggered, other participants are still in the room? Or do they leave? And the main issue is that one user can enter the room multiple times?

Comment: @lizziepika When I leave the room, participantdisconnected event triggered for myself and showing as other participant left the session. But they are exist in the room as active participants.